# Height 100% not working with fixed footer div

Tags: css, height, footer, fixed

css:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
.mframe {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 1024px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.header {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 125px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #666;
}
.navbar {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 55px;
    margin-top: 70px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #171717;
}
.content {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 250px;
    background-color: #333;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Lusitana", serif;
    color: #FFF;
}
.footer {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #111111;
}
```

html:

```
<body>
<div class="mframe">
    <div class="header">
        My Header
        <div class="navbar">
            Navbar
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Some Content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        My Footer goes here
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I have everything fine and if the content is more than the screen. I can scroll and the footer stays fixed. But if the content is less than the screen. I want my content div to fill up until the footer so I have a background color just on this div all the way down to the footer.

Here is my JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8BallDzigns/v6fV9/5/

Short Update:

I was thinking my fixed footer is causing a problem. But if I remove my footer from the html and leave just the content div in place. The mframe div is taking the whole page, but the content will not fill up to take up the remaining amount of the mframe div. I don't understand why the height and min-height is not working. I have tried height 100% and min-height 100% and height inherit. But none will work in any combination. I also tried margin-bottom: 0px and padding on the bottom. Still same situation.

Comment: Possible to provide jsfiddle? Thank you.

Comment: his jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4YvqW/

Comment: if you can apply a fixed height on the footer: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: Bill,I do have a fixed height. But on the example link you gave. If you continue to click on add content. Then the footer moves off screen and you have to scroll down to see it. That is not the affect I am looking for. The footer should stay static all the time and you can scroll the page to see additional content on some pages when the content is longer. I also want the content box to be filled in with a color and all the way to the footer when the content is shorter.

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem recently, there are examples already out there, but here is what worked for me:

```
html {
    height:100%;
}

body {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative; 
}

.mframe {
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: I tried addapting this and using your code. But it still doesn't work. I am still unable to get the background color of my content div to extend all the way to the footer.

Comment: Oh... sorry I see, your footer is fixed and you want the content div to extend down. Let me have another look.

Comment: Thanks. I have been searching and viewing other codes. But haven't found anything that works as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
.content {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

[this is your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/G9Zqx/5/) with `margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:100%;`

Comment: That doesn't work. Even if I try using padding at the height of my footer and margin 0. This way I can view all the text I put into the content div without the footer div blocking it. But the background of my content div is still now reaching the bottom.

Comment: oh, ok I think I see what you're talking about now.  because the position is fixed on the footer, it is removed from the normal flow.  see [this article](http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101) on positioning. set the .content margin-bottom to 0 and add padding-bottom to .content that is the same height as footer (50px).  you can see [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G9Zqx/2/) that the content is no longer cut off.  I've updated my answer above to reflect this

Comment: Chris, I tried this and on some pages it works fine, on other pages with minimal content, it causes issues and doesn't work. The background color stops short. If you take the fiddle example you provided and reduce the content to just one paragraph. You then see exactly my problem I am trying to fix that I keep hitting a dead end. Thanks for your help.

Comment: When would the content be less than a paragraph?

Comment: I am using this as a template for multiple pages. One page is an about section, 4 pages with services offered. Another with list of clients. They all have various amounts of content in them. This is where the issue is happening. I am trying to fix this that no matter how much content is inside. It appears correct with the background color filling in the page no matter how big a window someone has or screen size.

Comment: Chris, thanks. Now how do you get rid of the scroll bar on the right when there isn't enough content to fill up the page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52142/discussion-between-chris-m-and-johann)

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your specific problem, of wanting to extend the height of the content div, you could simply change the `min-height:100%` in `.content` to `min-height: 100vh;`

Comment: That does provide a solution. But then a problem is if the content is not the full height. I get a scroll bar on the right for the page to scroll to reach the bottom of the 100vh.